# Make seperate UI in android phones and tablets

Tags: android

Im developing an application which runs on phones and tablets, i wanted to use screen A,

for mobile(portrait) - listview to display data, once click on listview user should navigate to detail view.

for Tablets(portrait) - listview on leftside of the screen, once click on it the details should load on the right side of the sceen(instead of going to a new screen)

i can use views for phone and tablets separately in res/layout-large,medium for phones and res/layout-sw600dp,sw-720dp for tablets. but how can i handle the same java file for different layout mention above.

can i do this in the same apk, instead of giving seperate apk files to phones and tablets.

Comment: create layout for tablet in `layout-land`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, youu can build separate UI for tablet and mobile.

In addition to layout folder in res. Create following folders for layout of different size in res.

1. layout-large
2. layout-normal
3. layout-small
4. layout-xlarge

Put tablet and mobile layout with same name in them. See the magic of android. And use drawable with size for images and other xml.

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: i can use views for phone and tablets separately in res/layout-large,medium for phones and res/layout-sw600dp,sw-720dp for tablets. but how can i handle the same java file for different layout mention above.

Comment: You can code for all the component like listview and button. But before setting listener or any other task. Check is the component null or not. Example: ListView lv=(ListView)findBy.....);  if(lv!=null) { lv.set....}.

Comment: i got it now, checking all the widget for null in onCreate can use to manage one java class with different view design in the same project. Thanks.